# Meaningful interpretation for fixed point of a probability generating function

Tags: stochastic-processes, intuition, generating-functions

Suppose $f$ is the probability generating function for the [Galton-Watson branching process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galton%E2%80%93Watson_process).

What intuition makes the fact that $f(s) = s$ is the probability of extinction obvious? Moreover, can one find a meaningful interpretation for the "dummy variable", $s$? By meaningful, I mean an interpretation of $s$ which would allow us to write down that the root of $f(s) = s$ yields the extinction probability without needing to expand $f(s)$ to see the result.

Comment: As far as I know generating functions are defined as $f(s) = \mathbb{E}s^X$ for random variables $X$ (often with values in $\mathbb{N}_0$). What is the random variable $X$ in your case? Then $f(s) = s$ implies that $\mathbb{P}(X = 1) = 1$. Is this what you want?

Comment: Please omit the last two sentences in my first comment. You asked for the implications of $f(s) = s$ for some (not all) $0 < s < 1$.

Comment: If $p$ is the extinction probability and the first individual has $n$ children, then the conditional extinction probability is $p^n$. Therefore, $p=\mathbb{E}[p^n]$. With a proof that simple, what more intuition are you asking for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite shure, look in J.R. Norris, Markov Chains, Cambridge University Press, (1997), Example 5.1.1 (Branching Processes), in particular p. 172. Here you find that $s$ is the extinction probability, if $s = \inf \{t \in [0,1] \colon f(t) = t\}$. Here $f$ is the generating function of the random number $N$ of offsprings for each individual.

Comment: [Norris - Markov chains](https://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/statistics-probability/applied-probability-and-stochastic-networks/markov-chains) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1600720)).